# VB Error: "There is a already a datareader associated with this command"

Tags: sql, vb.net, servicestack

When attempting to run a ServiceStack service, I'm getting the following error:

When debugging, the code only runs once and does not cycle through twice, I've also put breakpoints on all other functions with datareaders and none of them are being hit first and therefore managed to narrow the issue down to this one function.

```
Public Function GetVisitList(SiteKey As String) As List(Of VisitDetail) Implements IVisitorData.GetVisitList
        Dim vlcmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        vlcmd.CommandTimeout = 60

        Try
            vlcmd.Connection = Conn
            vlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            vlcmd.CommandText = "GetVisitList"

            vlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitekey", SiteKey)

            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = vlcmd.ExecuteReader()

            Dim visitList As New List(Of VisitDetail)

            While dr.Read()
                Dim visit As New VisitDetail

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("VKey")) Then
                    visit.VisitorKey = dr("VKey")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("VisitIP")) Then
                    visit.IP = dr("VisitIP")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("SiteKey")) Then
                    visit.SiteKey = dr("SiteKey")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Alert")) Then
                    visit.AlertDescription = dr("Alert")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("AlertNo")) Then
                    visit.AlertNumber = dr("AlertNo")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("VisitNo")) Then
                    visit.VisitNumber = dr("VisitNo")
                Else
                    visit.VisitNumber = 0
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Invited")) Then
                    visit.Invited = dr("Invited")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Chatted")) Then
                    visit.Chatted = dr("Chatted")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Prospect")) Then
                    visit.Prospect = dr("Prospect")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Customer")) Then
                    visit.Customer = dr("Customer")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("HackRaised")) Then
                    visit.Hacker = dr("HackRaised")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Spider")) Then
                    visit.Spider = dr("Spider")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Cost")) Then
                    visit.ThisVisitCost = dr("Cost")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Revenue")) Then
                    visit.ThisVisitRevenue = dr("Revenue")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Visits")) Then
                    visit.Visits = dr("Visits")
                Else
                    visit.Visits = 0
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("FirstDate")) Then
                    visit.FirstVisitDate = dr("FirstDate")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("TotalCost")) Then
                    visit.TotalCost = dr("TotalCost")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("TotalRevenue")) Then
                    visit.TotalRevenue = dr("TotalRevenue")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("OperatingSystem")) Then
                    visit.OperatingSystem = dr("OperatingSystem")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Browser")) Then
                    visit.Browser = dr("Browser")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("SearchEngine")) Then
                    visit.SearchEngine = dr("SearchEngine")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Referrer")) Then
                    visit.Referrer = dr("Referrer")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Keywords")) Then
                    visit.Keywords = dr("Keywords")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("ReferrerQuery")) Then
                    visit.ReferrerQuery = dr("ReferrerQuery")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Name")) Then
                    visit.ContactName = dr("Name")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Email")) Then
                    visit.ContactEmail = dr("Email")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Company")) Then
                    visit.ContactCompany = dr("Company")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Telephone")) Then
                    visit.ContactTelephone = dr("Telephone")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Fax")) Then
                    visit.ContactFax = dr("Fax")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Street")) Then
                    visit.ContactStreet = dr("Street")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("City")) Then
                    visit.ContactCity = dr("City")
                    visit.City = dr("City")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Zip")) Then
                    visit.ContactZip = dr("Zip")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Country")) Then
                    visit.ContactCountry = dr("Country")
                    visit.Country = dr("Country")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Web")) Then
                    visit.ContactWebSite = dr("Web")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Organization")) Then
                    visit.Organization = dr("Organization")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("CRMID")) Then
                    visit.CrmID = dr("CRMID")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Notes")) Then
                    visit.ContactNotes = dr("Notes")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("DNS")) Then
                    visit.DNS = dr("DNS")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Region")) Then
                    visit.Region = dr("Region")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("FirstAlert")) Then
                    visit.FirstAlertDescription = dr("FirstAlert")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("FirstVisitReferrer")) Then
                    visit.FirstReferrer = dr("FirstVisitReferrer")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("ProspectTypes")) Then
                    visit.ProspectTypes = dr("ProspectTypes")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("VisitDate")) Then
                    visit.SessionStarted = dr("VisitDate")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("SecondsOnSite")) Then
                    visit.TimeOnSite = dr("SecondsOnSite")
                End If

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("Page")) Then
                    visit.Page = dr("Page")
                End If

                visitList.Add(visit)

                dr.Close()
                Conn.Close()
            End While

            Return visitList

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Function
```

The associated connection initialization is:

```
Public Sub Init(connectionString As String) Implements IVisitorData.Init
        connString = connectionString
        Conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Conn.Close()
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Conn.Open()
        End If
    End Sub
```

So far I've tried:

- Closing the connection
- Disposing the command
- Closing the datareader
- Deploying a check to only open the db connection if it's current state is closed

And none of these have worked. Does anybody have any idea what might be happening here? As far as I can see the datareader is only opened once then closed, but there must be something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the connection, command, and datareader into using statements [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).  It ensures the disposal of resources when the code is finished in the using block.  So here is the code that I would use:

```
using con as new sqlconnection("connection string")
     con.open()
     using command as new sqlcommand("sql string", con)
          'Your command code...
          using rdr as sqldatareader = command.executereader()
               'Your reader code...

          end using

     end using
end using
```

I think this is the best way to ensure your objects are disposed.

HTH

Wade

Answer (score 4):

```
  dr.Close()
  Conn.Close()
End While
```

These should be outside the while loop. You trying to read after you have closed the connection.

```
End While
  dr.Close()
  Conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kash' answer, you would be better of initializing a local instance of the SqlConnection class so it's internal to your function. The default implementation uses connection pooling on the background anyway ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)), so performance wise it doesn't make a difference.

The Using statement is also very beneficial. It provides the advantage that the connection is closed and disposed automatically when it is exited. It would've avoided your current issue too.

```
Using conn as new SqlConnection()
    conn.Open()
    ...
End Using
```